# ExifInterface cannot retrieve geotag of taken photo on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Making an app which should retrieve exif data from taken photos and store it in Room database. Below I provided with a code which I use for retrieving latitude and longitude of a picture and also a date. The following constructor is used for creating an object to store in the database. The thing is that this code works perfectly on a phone (both location and date are retrieved), but it doesn't work on an emulator only for location data (date is still retrieved). Calling `getLatLong()` method returns null.

```
public Picture(String picturePath, String title) {
    this.picturePath = picturePath;
    this.title = title;

    try {
        ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(picturePath);

        double latLong[] = exifInterface.getLatLong();
        this.lat = latLong != null ? latLong[0] : 0;
        this.lon = latLong != null ? latLong[1] : 0;

        this.date = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I double checked all the permissions and if a photo has location data. All the necessary permissions were granted and the photo has its location. 
[Inside the app, the location is 0.0 for both lat and long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJsjW.png).
[However, looking at the picture details, we can see that there is a location of 40.000 10.000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1SXp.png)

I've also managed to retrieve location on the emulator using `getAttribute()` but using `android.media.ExifInterface` instead of `android.support.media.ExifInterface`; Repeat, that this works on the phone, but not on the emulator ONLY.

My gradle file also has a dependency of `com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0`. Versions of Android on the emulator were both 9.0.0 and 8.0.0.

**UPDATE**
Get all the images using EasyImage. Here is what I'm doing in my MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    EasyImage.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, this, new DefaultCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onImagePickerError(Exception e, EasyImage.ImageSource source, int type) {
            //Some error handling
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onImagesPicked(@NonNull List<File> imageFiles, EasyImage.ImageSource source, int type) {
            onPhotosReturned(imageFiles);
            adapter.onPhotosReturned(imageFiles, recyclerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCanceled(EasyImage.ImageSource source, int type) {
            //Cancel handling, you might wanna remove taken photo if it was canceled
            if (source == EasyImage.ImageSource.CAMERA) {
                File photoFile = EasyImage.lastlyTakenButCanceledPhoto(MainActivity.this);
                if (photoFile != null) photoFile.delete();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void onPhotosReturned(List<File> returnedPhotos) {
    addImageElements(returnedPhotos);
}

private void addImageElements(List<File> returnedPhotos) {
    for (File file : returnedPhotos) {
        Picture element = new Picture(file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName());
        viewModel.getRepository().insert(element);
    }
}
```

And in PictureAdapter.java

```
private List<Picture> pictures = new ArrayList<>();
private static List<Picture> allPictures = new ArrayList<>();

void setPictures(List<Picture> pictures) {
    this.pictures = pictures;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

static void setAllPictures(List<Picture> allPictures) {
    PictureAdapter.allPictures = allPictures;
}

void onPhotosReturned(List<File> returnedPhotos, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    pictures.addAll(getImageElements(returnedPhotos));
    setPictures(pictures);
}

private List<Picture> getImageElements(List<File> returnedPhotos) {
    List<Picture> imageElementList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File file : returnedPhotos) {
        Picture element = new Picture(file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName());
        imageElementList.add(element);
    }
    return imageElementList;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `picturePath` is wrong. Where are you getting that value?

Comment: @CommonsWare I've updated the question, now it should be a bit clear. Also, would like to point out that (but I'm not sure about this one) the picture path seems to be all right as in my MainActivity I display all the pictures added into the db, and also their names are fine https://imgur.com/a/8RQu8pu.